# Slick multiple carousel and controls issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, slick.js

I have 3 carousels in one page under tabs. Carousels are working fine. But all the controls are appending to first carousel div. The first carousel-controls div has 3 previous and 3 next buttons. Other carousel-controls doesn't have any html.

```
$formatter.each(function(key) {
var thisFormatter = $(this);
var carousel = thisFormatter.find('.js-basic-carousel');
var arrowsDiv = thisFormatter.find('.carousel-controls');

//adding arrows like this
appendArrows: arrowsDiv
 }

// HTML is appending like this
<div class="carousel-controls">
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" 
 aria-label="Previous" role="button" style="display: 
 block;">Previous</button>
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" 
aria-label="Previous" role="button" style="display: 
block;">Previous</button>
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" 
aria-label="Previous" role="button" style="display: 
block;">Previous</button>
```

How can I get controls separately for each carousel?

Comment: can you share your code snippet here ?

Comment: Added code snippet .. -Thanks